# modifying ModelState on the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

So here's the problem: I have a form and a property adorned with `[RequiredAttribute]` altough initialy it's hidden on the form. There's a checkbox. 
When it's clicked it shows the element. So I wanted to validate the property only when it's not hidden, but on submit when it sends model to the controller I still see  `ModelState.IsValid == false` (although element it's hidden) so how can I remove all the errors related to the property when the element is hidden (in javascript, before browser sends model to the controller)?

modifying `$('form').validate().errorList` not helping

Of course I can have a boolean flag (`isHidden` or something) and check the model manually on the controller based on that flag. But maybe there's easier way to modify validation properties on the client, maybe somehow they affect Model?

Comment: Validation happens on the _server_.  You need to modify your server-side validators.

Comment: unobtrusive validation happens on the client though

Comment: Unobtrusive validation does not affect server validation in any way.  The code your trying to write can only work if there is a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: ""
    })
</script>
```

or you can consider making a custom validator.

[THIS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744530/413670) may help